# Write a Java webdriver selenium script to increase number of views on youtube video not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, youtube, ip-address

I wrote a Selenium script to increase the number of views of my youtube video. The current view count is: 164, I would like to increase this by 100. Here is my code below. The problem is that it seems that the browser automation does not increase the count even though the web page is accessed 100 times, what is the reason? Any fix? I was thinking maybe they know that I am accessing the website from the same IP address, maybe a change of IP address could fix this? If yes, how?

```
package Test;

// Generated by Selenium IDE
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class YoutubeAutomation {
  private static WebDriver driver;
  private Map<String, Object> vars;
  JavascriptExecutor js;
  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
  @AfterAll
  public static void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }
  public String waitForWindow(int timeout) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Set<String> whNow = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Set<String> whThen = (Set<String>) vars.get("window_handles");
        if (whNow.size() > whThen.size()) {
          whNow.removeAll(whThen);
        }
        return whNow.iterator().next();
      }
  @Test
  public void test() throws InterruptedException {
      
      String[] videosURLs = {"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ86JHQ9TCA&ab_channel=MounaCameliaHammoudi"
//           , "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nYbkKicMmA&ab_channel=MounaCameliaHammoudi", 
//            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F8AoqdHTs&ab_channel=MounaCameliaHammoudi", 
//            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ86JHQ9TCA&ab_channel=MounaCameliaHammoudi",
//            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhK5r9uyBTo&t=508s&ab_channel=MounaCameliaHammoudi",       
//            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgWxpdx8UGM&ab_channel=MounaCameliaHammoudi", 
//            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NC7Xq9CdBVk&ab_channel=MounaCameliaHammoudi",
//            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdtn4RYgCYM&ab_channel=MounaCameliaHammoudi"
              };
      for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
          for( String videoURL: videosURLs) {
              driver.get(videoURL);
               System.out.println("MOUNA CAMELIA "+i+"   "+videoURL);
               
          }
      }
    
        
}
}
```

Comment: 1. view does not count if minimum watching time is not reached. 2. view does not count if browser is running by a script. End of story, huh?

Comment: How to counter all these obstables and still have it increased through the script? There must be a trick!!

Comment: If you were YT, wouldn't you maximize your effort to filter robotic activities?

Comment: maybe but I am not YT, and I wanna find a trick to increase the views with my script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think views does not count when minimum watching time is not reached & of cours one ip adresse will not work to increase your views, you should alway change it & **for fix ip adresse problem you can use vpn extenion with selenium** i do something similar in that repo if you want to see : [Youtube_Watch_Bot](https://github.com/AbdeLhalimSB/Youtube_Watch_Bot)